# Error: react-native version in "package.json" doesn't match the installed version in "node_modules"

Tags: android, react-native

I ran `react-native-git-upgrade` so I can run `react-native run-android` later on to build my app on my device but an error message appeared.

The error says:

`Error: react-native version in "package.json" (https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz) doesn't match the installed version in "node_modules" (0.57.1).`

I tried running 'npm install' again but the error still occurs.

Comment: installed version on your system does not match with the version specified in your package.json file

Answer (score 1):

You are using Expo. You can't upgrade like this way. Expo using custom version of React Native.Check this. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough

and you are already using latest version of Expo.

Comment: Since I'm already using Expo, how do I build the app on my device if react-native run-android does not work?

Comment: you need to download Expo Client app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent   and for runnig app server with  ```npm start```  check this docs. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/workflow/up-and-running

Comment: how am i supposed to export the signed apk with expo? i am getting the same error and i cant create an android folder with react-native eject

Comment: you need to run ```expo eject ```